# C++ multithreading: managing threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a pool of N jobs and I would like to have a constant load of M (= number of CPUs) threads. How can I do that in C++?

I already know the basics of the thread library of C++. The easiest way is to enqueue M jobs and wait for all to finish. Then enqueue another M jobs. Do this as long as there are jobs left.

This simple approach works fine as long as each job/thread takes approximately the same amount of time. If this is not the case, it can easily happen that one long thread is still working while all other are finished. Thereby, only one of M CPUs are loaded.

So I need a kind of thread managing. Instead of waiting for all threads, I have to constantly check how many threads are running and enqueue a new one, if necessary.

Is there something similar already implemented in C++? Otherwise, what would be the easiest/smartest way implement such a manager?

Comment: read about thread pools, there are plenty of them in C++

Comment: There are multiple solution to your problem. One of them is to provide self managing threads and it's simple, when one of your threads is ending his job it just take firs not process job from job list. One thing you need to remember is to do a critical section for job taking operation.

Comment: Start N threads at the beginning and let them all stay running throughout the application.  Each thread then loops waiting for a condition variable, or a semaphore, or a bounded buffer, or a queue to have an item to process in it.

Answer (score 0):

> So I need a kind of thread managing. Instead of waiting for all threads, I have to constantly check how many threads are running and enqueue a new one, if necessary.
>
> Is there something similar already implemented in C++?

There is a [Task Scheduler in Intel Thread Building blocks library](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506100), which does load balancing of user tasks onto available CPUs in a highly-efficient fashion.